# How can I create a TTM value of a cumulated quarterly values in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, quantitative-finance

To be more precise: I want to use "capital expenditures", which is only available as FQ and FY, but as TTM values. How can I get these values in pine script. I have some general experience with pine script, but I currently can't find any solution.

The result should be just like other TTM values (revenue, ...).

Thanks in advance :)

The result should be just like other TTM values (revenue, ...).

Comment: Please explain the abbreviation used in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Just use the sum() function with the length of the past 4 quarters ...